# HOSTNAME missing from env output

Tags: linux, hostname

I've got this C code `getenv("HOSTNAME");`, which returns `NULL` on a VM running Linux (Guixsd).  While investigating I ran the following three commands, which work as expected:

`hostname` => `guixos`

`echo $HOSTNAME` => `guixos`

`cat /etc/hostname` => `guixos` (no newline)

So I expected hostname to also be printed out by env, but...

`env | fgrep HOST` =>

So, I've got three methods of accessing the hostname which actually work, and two which I expect to work, but don't.  Can someone explain why those two methods don't also give me the hostname?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HOSTNAME` is a variable that bash (but not other shells) sets by default. It is not exported.

Since it's not exported, it will not be inherited by `env` or any C program invoked from a bash shell.

Comment: dude... I never realized.  So that means... `HOSTNAME=$(echo $HOSTNAME) env | fgrep HOSTNAME`... yep! lol